# Filter on exact word in multiple lines of text file

Tags: python, filter

I have a text file that I'm reading. 
I want to filter these lines 
Example lines

```
5.254.739   478.661 P   PPL     NL      7   361
5.241.535   467.464 P   PPL     NL      7   392
5.238.084   463.683 P   PPLA    NL      7   392
5.260.252   468.815 P   PPLA2   NL      7   399
```

I want to filter only on 'PPL' so the rest should not be included

I tried it with code below
I also tried to apply regex but I keep failing in it

```
with open("source.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("new.txt", "w") as output:
        new_f = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for line in new_f:
            if "PPL" in line:
                output.write(line)
```

I would like to be able to filter the lines containing the exact word 
When filter on PPL the other lines like PPLA and PPLA2 should be ignored

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if condition to:

```
if "PPL" in line.split():
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
After changing the line it simply prints an empty file
@lostCode

I tried both " PPL " as wel as ' PPL '

Comment: @feremal I don't see a reason why it would behave so. Make sure you have made the exact changes as suggested.

Comment: I am using UTF-8 files btw
I dont know if that matters?

Comment: It works perfect
May i ask you why line.split needed to be used?

Comment: @feremal Most probably, check for " PPL " wasn't working because you have tabs in your file, instead of spaces, that's why the equality check failed. Now with splits, it returns a list or separate words, so we can directly check for "PPL" in the elements of list. You may try printing the output of line.split() to understand how it works.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It helped me a lot :-)
Now up to the next level. I want to add a new check (PPL and for example ADM1) slowly on i i will learn Python 
May i ask you where i can find some good help files on Python?
I want to read the "manual" so i dont have to keep asking "simp'le" questions like this